# How are spells in the Harry Potter universe made official?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

The actual invention of spells is not really important here, other than we know that they can be invented. After all, a bunch are mentioned in Half-Blood Prince that were invented by Snape in school.

Since this suggests that spells can be invented, it is reasonable to suppose that every one of them, from *Wingardium Leviosa* to *Avada Kadavra,* must have been invented at some time by someone.

So what is the difference between the above-mentioned spells and something like *Sectumsempra*, other than that one was written in the margin of a random textbook? What causes spells to become accepted as part of the charms canon, to the point where they are taught in Hogwarts in a certain year, suggesting that they have been investigated and their level of difficulty determined? Is there a department in the MoM that oversees this? Is it just done by smart people in ivory towers? And, if the former, what about spells used in other countries?

Comment: The careful and precise art of shouting syllables at your wand until something happens.

Comment: That is not the point of my question. That question seems to already have been answered on this site. I am not talking about how a spell is invented. I am asking how it is officiated.

Comment: The spells are chosen by the authors of the textbooks, it seems

Comment: So, before textbooks, do you think that anyone who learned spells would simply have learned those known by their master? I am talking pre-Hogwarts

Comment: Food for thought: are spells invented or discovered?

Comment: @DavidZ Definitely discovered, I would say. How would one go about _inventing_ magic that would then work for others too? Especially if they only saw the word you’re supposed to say without knowing what the spell does or anyone telling them what to do to get it to work.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would think so too... but it is magic, so one could imagine there is some global "registry" of spells, and when you invent a new spell, you can somehow submit it to that registry to make it available for everyone.

Comment: @DavidZ Could be, though I daresay a teenage Snape wouldn’t likely be running for any registries to submit _Sectumsempra_ for officiality.

Comment: Via Twitter. Anything Rowling twits is official.

Comment: @DavidZ The margins had variations on sectumsempra crossed out before the correct one was written down, definitely feels more like discovery than creation/registration

Comment: A real world analogue to this might be something like programming languages. There are dozens if not hundreds of languages, but only a small subset are actually used. This small subset is 1.) Popular 2.) Well understood 3.) Suitable for teaching new people

Comment: That registry idea sounds a little like what happens with cell lines and genetic structures to me. There are huge databases of genetic codes that you can match one you obtain against for the purpose of identification or phylogeny. With cell lines there are cell banks that store many samples of a particular cell line (and you can buy them if you can afford them).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, in this case the "registry" I had in mind wouldn't be controlled by the Ministry, or by any individual or group. It would be a fully natural phenomenon, unlike anything we know of in the real world. (The closest analogue might be a cryptocurrency blockchain, to which anyone can submit some information which is then recorded and accessible forever, although that's an artificial system, and is completely transparent, which a magical spell registry presumably would not be.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## The Ministry of Magic oversees the creation of all new spells.

Hermione is clear that the Ministry of Magic has a role in signing off new spells and checking they're safe. She was annoyed with the Half-Blood Prince because his spells didn't have this approval.

> "So you just decided to try out an unknown, handwritten incantation and see what would happen?"
>   "Why does it matter if it's handwritten?" said Harry, preferring not to answer the rest of the question.
>   "Because it's probably not **Ministry of Magic-approved**," said Hermione.
>   <sub>*(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 12, Silver and Opals)*.</sub>

We aren't given any further information about how the Ministry of Magic goes about this approval process. However, there is a body in the Ministry called the Committee on Experimental Charms which probably plays a role in determining whether new spells are safe.

> "Here comes Gilbert Wimple; he’s with the Committee on Experimental Charms; he’s had those horns for a while now..."
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 7, Bagman and Crouch)*.</sub>

As for cases of unlawful spell-creation, these are presumably handled by the Improper Use of Magic Office, which seems like the most relevant bureaucratic arm.

> "Level Two, Department of Magical Law Enforcement, including **the Improper Use of Magic Office**, Auror Headquarters and Wizenganot Administration Services."
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 7, The Ministry of Magic)*.</sub>

Of course, just because the Ministry has legal responsibility for overseeing new spells, that's not to say that they actually know what's happening on the ground. After all, all Animagi were meant to be registered with the Ministry and we know that several people flouted *those* rules. When it comes to making up new spells, we know that Snape did it without permission. It's likely that others created illicit spells as well.

As for how spells come to be taught, as Valorum says, the students learn the spells that are in the textbooks. The teachers are allowed to pick the textbooks themselves, since Hagrid selects the very Hagridy *Monster Book of Monsters*. So if someone thinks it's worth putting in a textbook and the teacher thinks that book is worth teaching then it will go on the syllabus. Presumably, authors check whether or not spells are Ministry of Magic-approved before they put them in their books.

Comment: Are the Unforgivable Curses Ministry-approved? While their use is, well, unforgivable, they still seem to be "official" spells and do have their usage ("Moody" was allowed to teach his students about them, for example).

Comment: @JAB 'Approved' and 'legal' are not necessarily the same thing. The Ministry can acknowledge a spell and then immediately pass a law against it if they choose to.

Comment: @JAB Doesn't someone (Umbrige, I think) use Moody teaching those spells as part of her proof that Hogwarts was mis-managed?

Comment: @KittenWithAWhip Yep. Then later tried to use one on a student herself. #hypocrite

Comment: "So you just decided to install an app from an unknown source and see what would happen?" :D

Comment: The Dark Lord doesn't like The Toad Umbridge. That's positive.

Comment: As a side note on teaching, all years are issued a _Standard Book of Spells_ by Miranda Goshawk, graded by difficulty. I would speculatively imagine this contains only Ministry-approved spells.

Comment: @Akshat Mahajan almost certainly. Like how IRL textbooks must match the government-approved syllabus (at least where I'm from).